# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: [ LARAVEL ]

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel-5, foreign-key-relationship

I created a new database and added some foreign keys, cause I didn't this in my database before that and my whole webpage got's many issues.. thats why I decided to create a new one, with all the foreign keys I need.

Now I created a new user on my webpage and it works.. But If I'm trying to create a thread with this user, I'm getting this error message:

---

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`Laravel`.`threads`, CONSTRAINT `threads_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`themen_id`) REFERENCES `themes` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `threads` (`themen_id`, `thread`, `content`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values ({id}, unicorn, rainbows, 1, 2016-03-23 14:11:23, 2016-03-23 14:11:23))

---

and below this error, nearly the same error again:

---

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`Laravel`.`threads`, CONSTRAINT `threads_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`themen_id`) REFERENCES `themes` (`id`))

---

well, I don't haven't a single idea, what this means. I hope someone of you can help me there.

Thats how I created the table:

```
CREATE TABLE threads 
(
    id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id int NOT NULL,
    themen_id int NOT NULL,
    thread varchar (120),
    content varchar (1200),
    created_at timestamp,
    updated_at timestamp,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (themen_id) REFERENCES themes(id)
);

CREATE TABLE comments 
(
    id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    thread_id int NOT NULL,
    user_id int NOT NULL,
    comment text,
    created_at timestamp,
    updated_at timestamp,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (thread_id) REFERENCES threads(id)
);

CREATE TABLE themes
(
    id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    thema text,
    created_at timestamp,
    updated_at timestamp    
);

CREATE TABLE users
(
    id int(10) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    email VARCHAR(255),
    password VARCHAR(60),
    remember_token VARCHAR(100),
    created_at timestamp,
    updated_at timestamp
);
```

I'm working with Laravel, of course I've changed the database name in the .env file. Well, I don't really now what to do right now.

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: `themen_id` expects integer but the error indicates that you sent a string `{id}`.

Comment: The error suggests that you're trying to insert a record into `threads` using a `themen_id` value that isn't present in `themes`.  The foreign key constraint exists specifically to prevent you from being able to do that.

Comment: There is no "Theme" with id = {id} which is what you're passing, that's what the foreign key should reference.

Answer (score 0):

Integrity issues not just from laravel are mostly because the foreign ID you used **DOES NOT EXIST** in the related table. So if you update/add a foreign key to a certain table, make sure it exists first.